# Finding the sum of the elements of an array, Java

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong when trying to get the sum and the average of the elements in the array? My assignment is: You are preparing for the Boston Marathon. In order to prepare, you need to train for 10 weeks, running an increasing number of miles per week, starting at running at least 2 miles your first week up to 26 miles by week 10. One question states to find the sum of the total miles ran over ten weeks and the average miles ran over the ten weeks, and what I have will execute without errors, but the sum is coming out as 26.000000000004 which I know is wrong. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I am new to this.

```
    public class arrayTest
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

          double[] miles = new double [10];

                double milesPerWeek = 26.0 / 10;
                double totalMiles = 0;
                double sum = 0;
                double average = 0;

                System.out.println("Week\tMiles");

                for (int i = 0; i < miles.length; i++)
                {
                      miles[i] += milesPerWeek;
                      totalMiles += miles[i];

                  System.out.println("Week " + i + " miles " + totalMiles);
                     }
                for (int i = 0; i < miles.length; i++)
                {              
                      sum = sum + miles[i];
                      average = sum / miles.length;
                   }
                  System.out.print("the sum of the miles ran is: " + sum + "\n");

                  System.out.print("the average miles ran is: " + average);
                }
          }
    The result reads:
    Week    Miles
    Week 0 miles 2.6
    Week 1 miles 5.2
    Week 2 miles 7.800000000000001
    Week 3 miles 10.4
    Week 4 miles 13.0
    Week 5 miles 15.6
    Week 6 miles 18.2
    Week 7 miles 20.8
    Week 8 miles 23.400000000000002
    Week 9 miles 26.000000000000004
    the sum of the miles ran is: 26.000000000000004
    the average miles ran is: 2.6000000000000005
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Well, I need the sum of the miles ran from all the weeks...2.6 + 5.2 + 7.8 etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your problem is that the Java `double` primitive is not exact in the way it handles floating point. (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more on that problem.)

If you want to avoid the problem, look into the BigDecimal class.

If you don't want to change it, there is literally nothing you can do.  It's a problem with the language itself, not anything you're doing.

Comment: You are correct to a point. You can't blame Java for IEEE 754's decimal flaws. All languages suffer this. `BigDecimal` is waaaay overkill for this.

Comment: Well, it does solve the problem.  But yes, it's probably not really worth it to do that, especially for this particular program.

Answer (score 0):

Try to format your output like this, using `printf` will allow you to keep control of the formatting of your output.

```
System.out.printf("Week " + i + " miles %.2f\n", totalMiles);
```

---

### Output

```
Week    Miles
Week 0 miles 2,60
Week 1 miles 5,20
Week 2 miles 7,80
Week 3 miles 10,40
Week 4 miles 13,00
Week 5 miles 15,60
Week 6 miles 18,20
Week 7 miles 20,80
Week 8 miles 23,40
Week 9 miles 26,00
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote whoever...

Comment: +1 Yeah, it's the correct answer. Though 1dp is enough and the week number could go in the format string and should use `%n`: `System.out.printf("Week %d miles %.1f%n", i + 1, totalMiles);`